# From $.getJSON to XMLHttpRequest

Tags: javascript, jquery, json, jquery-mobile, cordova

I use the following script to create dynamic pages in Jquery Mobile/Phonegap based on a JSON-file.

```
function loadMovie(movies){
   $('#indexList').empty();

   //add the movie items as list
   $.each(movies, function(i, index){
     $('#indexList').append(generateIndexLink(index));
   });

   //refresh the list view to show the latest changes
   $('#indexList').listview('refresh');
}

$.getJSON("exp1_index.json", loadMovie);

//creates a movie link list item
function generateIndexLink(index){

return '<li><a href="javascript:void(0)'
    + '" onclick="goToIndexDetailPage(\''
    + index.naam
    + '\',\''
    + index.img +'\')">'
    + index.naam
    + '<img src="'
    + index.img + '"/><br>'
    + index.kunstwerk + '</a></li>';
}

function goToIndexDetailPage(indexNaam, indexImg){

var indexPage = $("<div data-role='page' data-url=dummyUrl><div data-role='header'><h1>"
              + indexNaam + "</h1></div><div data-role='content'><img src='"
              + indexImg + "'/></div><div data-role='footer'><h4>"
              + indexNaam + "</h4></div></div>");

indexPage.appendTo( $.mobile.pageContainer );

//go to the newly created page
$.mobile.changePage( indexPage );
}
```

Thing is that the URL of my JSON-file also has to be dynamically injected. For this I use Phonegap's filesystem. However, this doesn't work well with $.getJSON, but it does work with XMLHttpRequest, like for example:

```
function loadHome() {
var request = new XMLHttpRequest();
request.open("GET", pathHome, true);
request.onreadystatechange = function() {//Call a function when the state changes.
if (request.readyState == 4) {
  if (request.status == 200 || request.status == 0) {

  var home = JSON.parse(request.responseText);
  var data = "<table cellspacing='0'>";
  for (i = 0; i < home.length; i++) {
    data += "<td>";
    data += "<a data-ajax='false' href='" + home[i].link + "'/>";
    data += "<figure><img src='" + home[i].img + "'/>";
    data += "<figcaption>" + home[i].expo + "<br><em>";
    data += home[i].datum + "</em></figcaption></figure></a></td>";
  }
  data += "</table>";
  var twitter = document.getElementById("home");
  twitter.innerHTML = data;
  }
}
}
    console.log("asking for home");
    request.send();
}
```

So my question is how I can turn the script creating dynamic pages into one with an XMLHttpRequest instead of $.getJSON. My Javascript/Jquery skills aren't as good as they should be to solve this. So I hope someone here could give me tips or advice on how to make this work.